# JavaScript - passing variable to regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to do some sort of searching with this:

```
if (v.name.search(new RegExp(/peter/i)) != -1) {
    console.log('found peter's record');
}
```

But how can I put a variable into that regular expression? I have tried with `v.name.search(new RegExp('/'+var+'/i'))`, but it didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you expecting the variable to contain? A proper regex like `[a-z]` or `peter`?

Answer (score 3):

That should be:

```
if (v.name.search(new RegExp(myVar, "i")) != -1) {
    console.log('found '+ myVar +' record');
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp) for further info.